# Relay inside oscilloscope (Relay vs other switches)

Tags: analog, relay, oscilloscope

When I press the "Auto" button on my scope, I can hear the sound of a relay switching (several relays or single relay switching many times.)

What are the relays doing?

Comment: A relay is used where the input circuit switching needs to withstand conditions which semiconductor switching cannot easily do without impacting the signal.   Portable scopes tend to have many compromises of capability, such are more limited input range or more distortion of the signal being measured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably used in the "front end" (the parts closest to the input section) for range switching/input attenuators. When you switch your oscilloscope to auto it has no idea high big or small the signal might be (mV or tens of volts), so it will try to set the range such that the signal is easily visible on the screen without going beyond the boundaries.

Mechanical switches and relays are far more "ideal" than semiconductor switches in this kind of situation. Lower resistance, less leakage, less stray capacitance and able to handle high voltages. They are not so good at fast switching or long life under load, but neither of those are requirements for range switching.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit "Auto" it scans through different V/div attenuation settings and makes a measurement to decide which V/div setting to use for each channel.

The different V/div settings are separated by relays in the oscilloscope front end. To dig in more, you can check out this talk from one of our oscilloscope ADC designers:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzHyxysSubUmxGOMVpiKLxouweh2AAlG1

If you want to get to the attenuator part go to vid 3.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in analog electronics a relay is the best thing to use because the contact resistance is fixed and does not degrade the signal. One can also use analog muxes (a pmos and nmos in parallel usually), but the resistance is dependent on the voltage, and their is leakage and coupling, which present challenges.

A typical relay can have mΩ's of contact resistance, an analog mux resistance curve looks like this:

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1611_1612_1613.pdf

Another thing is size and power. Relays use more power, and occupy more space and are less desirable for portable applications

Comment: OK, but why the switching process needed in the scope?

Comment: To facilitate different gains, most ADC's take less than a 5V range these days, so if the scope has variable input ranges. The probes also might need switching. Both examples are shown here: http://alternatezone.com/electronics/images/mk3anal.gif

Comment: latching relays can mitigate power concerns but are more expensive than regular relays